# Creating a residual plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently trying to visualize my data, to find out if it is normally distributed or not, by doing a residual analysis.It seems to be very easy to do a residual graph using built in R functionality, but I prefer ggplot :). I keep running in to the issues of functions not being found, most recently the .fitted function.

My code is as following:

```r
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Data_proj,
       aes(x = x1/1000,
           y = as.numeric(y))) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
      facet_wrap(~x2)

ggplot(Data_proj, aes(x = .fitted, .resid)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0)
```

the error message I get is:

```
Error in `geom_point()`:
    ! Problem while computing aesthetics.
    ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
    Caused by error in `FUN()`:
    ! object '.fitted' not found
    Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you and have a great day!

Edit:
My data looks like this:

```
data <- tibble::tibble(
  x1 = c(8135, 1629, 2824, 9780, 8856, 10387),
  x2 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
  y = c("92.1281", "52.3726", "49.3202", "195.8212", "100.8019", "113.7111"),
  .fitted = c(
    `1` = 128.689193244635,
    `2` = 45.2529218882561,
    `3` = 60.5782130457833,
    `4` = 149.785514545164,
    `5` = 137.935665984866,
    `6` = 157.569992982502
  ),
  .resid = c(
    `1` = -36.5610932446345,
    `2` = 7.11967811174389,
    `3` = -11.2580130457833,
    `4` = 46.0356854548364,
    `5` = -37.1337659848664,
    `6` = -43.8588929825017
  ),
)
```

Comment: I would also recommend the function `performance::check_model()` which provides a lot of informative residual diagnostic plots for a linear model object, in pretty ggplot2 style. The performance package is part of [easystats](https://easystats.github.io).

Comment: Do you have columns `.fitted` and `.resid` in `Data_proj`? Can you include the output of `dput(head(Data_proj))`

Comment: @ConorNeilson included it in the post :)

Answer (score 2):

You did not specified the data and model: Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(.fitted, .resid)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0)+
  labs(title='Residual vs. Fitted Values Plot', x='Fitted Values', y='Residuals')
```

[image]

Comment: Very insightful. Thanks!